# Drawing bezier on top of existing mesh

Tags: opengl, geometry, computational-geometry, direct3d

I have a 3D mesh and I'd like to draw 3D bezier lines on its surface. What would the best approach be?

Assume I have all necessary code to draw the mesh, pick points on its surface and draw beziers based on those points.

A naive approach would be to simply pick some points and draw a bezier that goes through them, but that could intersect the mesh (on be above it) rather than being on its surface. Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "on be above it" ?

Comment: That's not so easy. One way would be to compute a parameterization of the mesh (e.g. texture coordinates), define the Bezier curve in this space and lift it onto the surface. However, this approach will give you problems at seems and with highly distorted parameterizations. Another option would be to employ a subdivision scheme and project the subdivided points back onto the mesh. But this will not produce a proper Bezier curve and the projection operation is usually not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to place a curve on mesh triangles. In that case curve can't be smooth (derivative is not continuous.) That it because mesh is not smooth on triangle edges.

If it is not a problem, than simple solution can be to split curve in parts for each triangle it crosses by choosing curve end control points on mesh edges. I am not sure how to do this, probably by looking for nearest point on mesh edges to discretized input curve.

Part of Bezier curve is Bezier curve, so after splitting input curve, existing drawing code can be used.